# NVIDIA GeForce Go 7150M (UMA) USB install

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I upgraded to ubuntu 14.04 from a clean install.  I do not have the NVIDIA GeForce Go 7150M (UMA) driver saved on the PC anywhere only on a USB drive.  I cannot get the PC to boot up passed the loggin screen to install the driver.  The graphic card fails even when i try to boot in "safe mode".

Is there anyway to install this driver from the prompt? Or do you have any other ideas to fix the problem?

Thanks!